# Approximation of optimum for two linear programs

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, estimation

Suppose you got two linear programs.

They are the same except that one has a shifted objective by a positive constant

(1)
$$\min c^Tx$$

(2)
$$\min c^Tx + d$$

For (2) there exists a 10-approximation, that means a algorithm that produces a solution $s_2$ at maximum ten times as bad as the optimal solution $s_2^*$:

$$ \frac{s_2}{10} \le s_2^* $$

The Question is what approximation ratio has (1) if you got a approximate solution $s_2$?

What i came up with

$$ s_2 - d= s_1 $$
$$ s_2^* - d = s_1^* $$

$$ \frac{s_1 + d}{10} \leq s_1^* + d $$

$$ \frac{s_1 - 9d}{10} \leq s_1^* $$

but this doesn't seem correct: if $d > s_1$ this is negative.

Thank you

Comment: Because $d$ can be arbitrarily large, I am not sure you can claim anything stronger than the trivial observation that the approximation factor is still at most 10.

Comment: Unforuntally the approximation ratio is worse.

Comment: (1) and (2) are equivalent - they have the same set of minimizers. Any sensible approximation scheme should therefore ignore the variable $d$ completely.